# Using enumerate to label points on a plot with a different letter for each point

Tags: python, matplotlib, enumerate

I am trying to print each point with a label that says Point A/B/C/D (- depending on which point it is) and the coordinates of each point. 
At the moment, all the points have the same letter but I would like them to be individual to the point. I have tried other ways but none have worked.

```
no_points = 4
list_no_points = list(range(no_points))
xs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
ys = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

plt.plot(xs, ys, linestyle = '--', marker = 'o', color = 'r')

for xy in zip(xs, ys):
    for x,i in enumerate(list_no_points):
        list_no_points[x] = string.ascii_uppercase[i]
    plt.annotate(f' Point ' + list_no_points[x] + ' (%.3f, %.3f)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the 2nd nested for, and your string line can be inserted directly into the annotation:

```
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

no_points = 4
list_no_points = list(range(no_points))
xs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
ys = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
plt.plot(xs, ys, linestyle = '--', marker = 'o', color = 'r')

for i, xy in enumerate(zip(xs, ys)):
    plt.annotate(f' Point ' + string.ascii_uppercase[i] + ' (%.3f, %.3f)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The points all have the same letter in your code because `x` is only changing in the inner for loop. The inner for loop is not necessary for your purpose. Try something like:

```
no_points = 4
list_no_points = list(range(65, 65 + no_points))
xs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
ys = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

plt.plot(xs, ys, linestyle = '--', marker = 'o', color = 'r')

for i, xy in enumerate(zip(xs, ys)):
    plt.annotate(f' Point ' + chr(list_no_points[i]) + ' (%.3f, %.3f)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data')

plt.show()
```

You can get the ASCII character corresponding to an integer using `chr` ('A' is 65)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility, but it avoids using enumerate in favor of letting the loop adjust the character selection:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string

xs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
ys = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

plt.plot(xs, ys, linestyle = '--', marker = 'o', color = 'r')

letter = 0
for xy in zip(xs, ys):
    plt.annotate(f' Point ' + string.ascii_uppercase[letter] + ' (%.3f, %.3f)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data')
    letter += 1

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    no_points = 4
    labels = [string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i in range(no_points)]

    xs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    ys = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xs, ys, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='r')

    for count, label in enumerate(labels):
        ax.annotate(f"{label}({xs[count]}, {ys[count]})", xy=(xs[count], ys[count]))
    plt.show()
```

---

And the output will be as expected:

[image]